# Dúvida sobre SEO. H1 no header e article?

Tags: html, html5, seo

Estava dando um estudada sobre montar uma página com estrutura preparada para SEO.

Vi alguns video e isso me gerou uma dúvida:

Dentro do meu `<body>`, tenho:

- `<header>` com H1;
- `<main> <article>` com outro H1;

Como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Coloquei meu site para medir o SEO e acusa que estou usando doi H1 na mesma página.

### Pergunta:

Qual seria a forma correta, devo usar o H1 no `<header>` ou no `<main> <article>`?

*Lembrando que no `<header>` o texto não aparece, seria usado apenas para SEO.*

Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Qual teste, ou em qual lugar que vc fez o teste que acusou problema por ter 2 H1?

Comment: @hugocsl agora não lembro mais, fiz a pesquisa no google por sites que fazem verificação de SEO e um deles acusou isso. Estou fazendo errado ou certo?

Comment: Cara sem um fonte comprovada, de preferencia do próprio Google, que fale que eh errado 2 h1 vc não deve confiar.  Se isso eh tão errado assim deveria ser muito fácil achar um fonte confiável que comprove isso não acha? Se vc viu em vários lugares e só um falou que não devia usar Pq vc vai confiar justo nele? A não ser que ele seja o proprio Google eh claro...

Comment: QUEM NEGATIVOU A PERGUNTA PODERIA EXPLICAR O MOTIVO?

Comment: @hugocsl realmente estou fazendo da forma correta. Acredito que o site que usei estava desatualizado. Veja essa materia https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/descomplicando-seo-posso-usar-mais-de-uma-tag-h1-na-p-marques-junior/

Comment: Minha primeira reação ao ler a pergunta foi *não tem como responder de forma assertiva*. Talvez seja esse o motivo da negativação.

Comment: @AugustoVasques vocês não podem julgar por simplesmente não saber escrever de uma forma que se faça entender em total plenitude. Cabe humildade dos colegas editarem a questão para melhor entendimento de todos.

Comment: @Tiago Primeiro que não votei na questão, [prova de que não votei](https://imgur.com/aRI6wCz). Segundo que você mesmo nesse [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/456022/d%c3%bavida-sobre-seo-h1-no-header-e-article?noredirect=1#comment869510_456022) pediu que apresentassem um motivo para os negativos, eu apenas sugeri um possível motivo. Agora se você se magoou com um voto que não aconteceu por conta de um comentário que você pediu a culpa não é minha de você estar se sentindo assim.

Comment: Ler o meu comentário na [resposta do Rafa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/456022/d%c3%bavida-sobre-seo-h1-no-header-e-article?noredirect=1#comment869529_456040) talvez o ajude a entender o porque das pessoas reagirem com ceticismo quando alegou os resultados de um *teste de SEO*.

Answer (score 2):

Todas as referências usadas nessa resposta são originais em **inglês**, então todas as traduções foram realizadas livremente. Aviso isso aqui para não precisar avisar sempre que houver uma citação.

### Para que servem as tags de cabeçalho?

É importante pensar na semântica do elemento. Uma tag não deve ser usada por causa de sua estilização, as sim por seu significado semântico. Conforme [especificações da W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/dom.html#heading-content), temos:

> O conteúdo do cabeçalho define o cabeçalho de uma seção (seja explicitamente marcado usando elementos de seção de conteúdo (*sectioning content*) ou implícitamente no próprio conteúdo do cabeçalho).

No seu caso, não faz sentido usar dentro do `<header>` se ele não for aparecer, e dentro do `<main>` ele estará servindo como um cabeçalho **implícito**, pois ele não é uma seção de conteúdo, conforme as [especificações](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/grouping-content.html#elementdef-main):

> O elemento `<main>` não é uma [seção de conteúdo](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/dom.html#sectioning-content) e não tem efeito no esboço do documento.

E, caso esteja curioso sobre quais são os elementos de seção de conteúdo, aqui está uma lista: `<article>`, `<aside>`, `<nav>` e `<section>`. Lembrando que a seção de conteúdo é o conteúdo que define o escopo de cabeçalhos (*headings*) e rodapés (*footers*).

### O que dizem os Google Webmasters sobre o `<h1>` em relação ao SEO?

Google Webmasters, nesse contexto, são as pessoas do Google que tem a capacidade e autoridade de auxiliarem e responderem em questões sobre o *Google Search Engine*, no sentido de como o seu site pode desempenhar melhor no mecanismo de busca do Google.

Num Hangout da Central do Google Webmaster (Setembro/2019, [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rwpwq8Ynf7s&feature=youtu.be&t=1427)), a seguinte questão é abordada:

> É obrigatório ter uma tag `<h1>` por página ou se ela pode ser utilizada múltiplas vezes?

[John Mueller](https://twitter.com/JohnMu) respondeu:

> E especialmente no HTML5, ter vários elementos `<h1>`em uma página é
>   completamente normal e meio que esperado. Portanto, não é algo com que
>   você precise se preocupar. E algumas ferramentas de SEO sinalizam isso
>   como um problema e dizem "oh, você não tem nenhuma tag `<h1>`" ou "você
>   tem duas tags `<h1>`". Do nosso ponto de vista, essa não é uma questão
>   crítica. Do ponto de vista da usabilidade, talvez faça sentido
>   melhorar isso. Portanto, não é que eu ignoraria completamente essas
>   sugestões, mas não a consideraria uma questão crítica.
>
> Seu site pode funcionar perfeitamente sem tags `<h1>` ou com cinco tags
>   `<h1>`.

Essa resposta reforça aquilo que foi dito no tópico anterior, de que é importante usar a tag de maneira semântica, onde ela tenha o significado correto. Você pode ter zero, uma, duas ou várias tags `<h1>` por página, mas reflita se realmente faz sentido todas serem `<h1>`. Provavelmente você deveria usar outros níveis de cabeçalho nessa página.

Em [outro vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyqJJXWk0gk) do John Mueller, dessa vez respondendo especificamente uma questão sobre cabeçalhos, múltiplos `<h1>` e acessibilidade:

> Nossos sistemas não têm problemas em lidar com múltiplas tags `<h1>`
>   em uma página, esse é um padrão justo e comum na Web. Nós usamos
>   cabeçalhos para entendermos melhor o contexto de diferentes partes de
>   uma página. Ter cabeçalhos semanticamente claros é útil para entender
>   qualquer página.
>
> Entretanto, nós temos que trabalhar com a Web como a encontramos, e
>   uma boa parte disso não é nem um pouco semanticamente estruturado.
>   Para os usuários, a diferença é mínima, ambos os tipos de página pode
>   ser extremamente relevante para a questão que eles tem. Por sua vez,
>   nossos sistemas não são muito exigentes e tentamos trabalhar com o
>   HTML da maneira que o encontramos, seja ele com:
>
> - Um único cabeçalho `<h1>`
> - Múltiplos cabeçalhos `<h1>`
> - Pedaços de texto estilizados (sem o uso de HTML semântico)
>
> Em resumo, quando pensando sobre esse assunto, SEO não deveria ser o
>   seu objetivo principal. Em vez disso, pense nos seus usuários. Se você
>   tem maneiras de tornar o seu conteúdo acessível para eles, seja por
>   usar múltiplas tags `<h1>` ou outras construções HTML padrão, isso não
>   atrapalhará seus esforços de SEO.

### Google SEO Report

Se isso tudo ainda não te convenceu que a tag `<h1>` deve ser usado conforme seu significado semântico e onde for pertinente, trago aqui mais uma referência do Google, dessa vez um pouco mais antiga (Março, 2010). No [Google SEO Report](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en/us/webmasters/docs/google-seo-report-card.pdf) temos o seguinte:

> [image: Foto de exemplo do Google utilizando h3 como cabeçalho]
>
> Use tags `<h1>` - a maioria das páginas principais do produto tem a
>   oportunidade de usar uma tag `<h1>`, como no exemplo acima, mas no
>   momento estão usando outras tags de cabeçalho (`<h3>` neste caso) ou
>   um estilo de fonte maior. Embora estilizar seu texto para que ele
>   pareça maior possa obter a mesma apresentação visual, ele não fornece
>   o mesmo significado semântico para o mecanismo de pesquisa que uma tag
>   `<h1>`. É ótimo ter o nome do produto e / ou algumas palavras sobre
>   seus recursos em uma tag `<h1>` para a página principal do produto.

---

### Experimento com a tag `<h1>` vs `<h2>`

Se você não achou que entendeu tudo sobre `<h1>` até agora, sério, veja os vídeos do John Mueller e saia dessa neura. Por motivos de conhecimento, resolvi compartilhar aqui também uma pesquisa de comparação entre o uso de tag `<h2>` no lugar da `<h1>`. Essa pesquisa está no artigo [Are H1 Tags Necessary for Ranking? [SEO Experiment]](https://moz.com/blog/h1-seo-experiment).

O artigo citado mostra um experimento onde utiliza como o título do artigo uma tag `<h1>` ou uma tag `<h2>` (sem tag `<h1>` no site), através de testes A/B pelo período de 8 semanas medindo o tráfego orgânico:

> [image: Gráfico dos testes A/B mostrando pouca variação de resultados em tráfego orgânico]
>   Para os não iniciados, esses gráficos podem ser um pouco difíceis de decifrar. Rida Abidi, da Distilled, dividiu os dados para nós assim:
>
> Impacto das alterações - inconclusivo
>   Elevação prevista: 6,2% (est. 6.200 sessões orgânicas mensais)
>   Estamos 95% confiantes de que o aumento mensal nas sessões orgânicas se situa entre:
>   Alta: 13.800
>   Baixa: -4.100
>   Os resultados deste teste foram inconclusivos em termos de tráfego orgânico; portanto, recomendamos revertê-lo.

Ou seja, alterar `<h2>` (que é a situação original do Site) por `<h1>` não resultou em uma diferença estatisticamente significativa. Mais uma vez, isso reforça o que foi dito nas fontes do Google: faça pelo seu usuário, não por SEO.

---

### Bônus - SEO Starter Guide

O Google possui um [SEO Starter Guide](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7451184) com um tópico específico para *[Headings](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7451184#headingtags)*, mas sem citar diretamente o nível do cabeçalho (`<h1>`, `<h2>` etc.).

Apesar disso, destaco os seguintes pontos sobre *Headings* (tradução livre):

> Semelhante a escrever um esboço para um artigo grande, pense um pouco
>   sobre quais serão os principais pontos e sub-pontos do conteúdo da
>   página e decida onde usar as tags de cabeçalho adequadamente.
>
> (...)
>
> Use tags de cabeçalho onde isso fizer sentido. Muitas tags de
>   cabeçalho em uma página podem dificultar a análise dos usuários de
>   determinarem onde um tópico termina e o outro começa.

Mais uma vez temos recomendação **oficial** de usar tags de cabeçalho conforme seu significado semântico, seguindo então a hierarquia de níveis de cabeçalho. Vale a leitura do guia para entender outros pontos avaliados no SEO.

---

OBS: Sobre o comentário do @hugocsl, onde ele [citou essa questão do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/665037/8839059), encontrei um total de zero fontes confiáveis falando sobre o uso de imagem no lugar texto dentro do `<h1>` e por isso não foi citado na resposta. A resposta do SOen possui muitos votos, em 2009 talvez fizesse sentido, já hoje, depois de tudo o que foi demonstrado aqui, posso dizer que não faz sentido.

Comment: Se quem negativou a resposta quiser explicar porque uma apresentação de testes, citações do guia de SEO do Google e de um *Webmaster Trends Analyst* do Google não torna essa resposta útil, estou à disposição de ouvir as críticas

Comment: Jovem não  foi eu  que negativei, mas vou te dar um toque para deixar a sua resposta mais completa. Na pergunta o cara questiona  se o H1 deve vir no Header ou em algum lugar dentro do Main. E sobre o H1 é muito comum técnicas para não usar texto dentro do H1 e sim  uma imagem de Logo por exemplo, recomendo vc dar uma olhada aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665037/replacing-h1-text-with-a-logo-image-best-method-for-seo-and-accessibilitytem vários outros links web a fora sobre isso. Assim talvez quem  deu o voto pense em remove-lo...

Comment: @hugocsl obrigado pelo comentário. Melhorei a resposta incluindo citações das especificações da W3 e do próprio Google. No fim, a resposta continua basicamente a mesma (use `<h1>` semanticamente), mas com uma base mais sólida.

Comment: Dei +1, para tirar os negativos, é uma boa resposta, mas @RafaelTavares a OBS é desnecessária. Acredito que o autor da pergunta levou vários negativos por uso de imagem.

Comment: Mandei o +1 por que achei util a resposta e ponderei que as considerações podem e devem ser levadas em conta na tomada de decisões para construção de conteúdo. Porém uma premissa sobre SEO que deve ser levada em conta é que não existem afirmações verdadeiras em SEO pois o algorítimo de classificação do google é uma caixa preta e tomar ponderações como afirmações tente a superstição.

Comment: @AugustoVasques concordo em partes. Minha resposta antes da edição dizia "Não é possível confirmar sem fazer testes, já que o cálculo do SEO não é divulgado", mas achei válido afirmar informações passadas pelo próprio Google e pelos Google Webmasters. Claro que o que eles dizem é algo dedutível a partir do bom senso, mas como foi citado, essa questão tem pouco impacto no SEO, o mais importante nesse aspecto é atender bem os clientes/usuários.

Comment: @AugustoVasques concordo plenamente! E mesmo que alguma regra SEO seja efetiva hj, pode não ser amanha... o Google vive mudando as regras de ranqueamento etc... Inclusive dia 28/05, duas semanas atrais eles já deram algumas pistas do que vai ganhar peso https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2020/05/evaluating-page-experience.html?m=1 Isso ai Rafa o importante é sempre a UX, mesmo que na tela o seu H3 seja mais "visível", paro o leitor de tela o que vale é o uso correto das tags. E sobre uma tag IMG dentro do H1, não sei se é correto, mas é muito comum de se ver por ai até hoje... 